# jQuery/jQuery UI/ Javascript "live" get() in HTML

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, get

is it possible to make a jquery/javascript call like

```
<span onclick="$('#dialog-2').html($.get('http://url.com');">Info</span>
```

direct from html code ?

i would like to get the content from a url direkt in code - into a current opened dialog box (http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the `load()`function: http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
<span onClick="$('#dialog-2').load('http://url.com')">Info</span>
```

Comment: well its not working for me here -.- ... the span will show in the "#dialog-2" maybe any other solution ?

Comment: i have try it with a call like ...load('file.php?id=...') this works - but with a domain -.-

Comment: ok jquery doesnt allow it with a "new" domain - i have rebuild the url so your post does work :) thanks